# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values - RowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to change navigate url property in row data bound event. if that coloumn not binded with link i want to add navigate url= #

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reportd Link"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:HyperLink ID="Lbl_RptLnk1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("ReportLinks")%>'
                            Text='Reported Link' Target="_blank" ToolTip='<%#Eval("ReportLinks")%>'></asp:HyperLink>

                 </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

aspx.cs code

```
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink myLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[0];//slno,linkname,linkid,link

        if (myLink.NavigateUrl == "Waiting for Approval")
        {
            myLink.NavigateUrl = "#";
        }

    }
```

getting error saying- Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

Comment: If you are adding `runat="server"`, use asp.net Button control

Comment: getting error while using asp button ... Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' does not have a public property named 'ItemStyle'.

Comment: If you want to use `Button`, then it should be inside `<asp:TemplateField />` and you can apply `ItemStyle` child to that field, not for `Button` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx)

Comment: Do share your `Gridview` markup as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `RowDataBound` event since your control is an ASP server control inside `TemplateField`, you can use the `FindControl` method on the row to find the control:-

```
HyperLink Lbl_RptLnk1 = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("Lbl_RptLnk1");
if (Lbl_RptLnk1.NavigateUrl.Trim() == "Waiting for Approval")
{
     Lbl_RptLnk1.NavigateUrl = "#";
}
```

Comment: yes, button creating problem. so i replaced with hyperlink. runat server and onclick at a time not working